# Is it possible "where + preposition(at)"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I think 3 of them are right.

> 1. I cannot go to **where** I was raped.
> 2. I cannot go to **the place where** I was raped.
> 3. I cannot go to **the place that** I was raped **at**.

But, I'm not sure this one is right.

> 4. I cannot go to **where** I was raped **at.**

Can you just tell me which one is acceptable and not from 1 to 4?

Comment: To is required in #1. #2 is 0K. At, though unnecessary, can be used in informal English. #4 sounds 0K.

Comment: @Khan *To* is **not** required in #1.

Comment: StoneyB,  Thanks for correcting me. It was a typo. Not was inadvertantly left out..

Answer (score 1):

1. I cannot go to where I was raped.

The word 'where' in the sentence has been used as a conjunction that means "to a place in which".  So the use of the preposition  'to' is unnecessary in the sentence. We should go where it's quieter (The Free Dictionary).

2. I cannot go to the place where I was raped.

The sentence is correct grammatically.  The 'where' has been used as a relative pronoun that also means  at or in a place in which".

3. I cannot go to the place that I was raped at.

This sentence is also OK; that has been used as a relative pronoun. The preposition 'at' in the end position sounds correct.

4. I cannot go to where I was raped at.

In light of explanation for the sentence #1, if you remove the prepositions to and at, the sentence will sound natural.

Answer (score 0):

Some people who are so pedant say "you can never end the sentence with a preposition". Some agree, others don't.

There are two types of relative pronouns. One is the type which requires antecedents such as which, who, that, etc. and  the other one doesn't always require antecedents. No. 1 is the example for the latter. Some call it ***headless relative pronoun*** or ***relative adverb***. Whichever it is called, it has a different function from the former.

> I cannot go to the place at (in) ***which*** I was raped.

In the above sentence, the antecedent of the relative pronoun *which* is *the place*. Without this antecedent, *which* can't be used. ***at which*** or ***in which*** can be changed to ***where*** as in:

> I cannot go to the place ***where*** I was raped.

If you put a preposition *at* or *in* after "raped", it would be ungrammatical because you are repeating the same preposition twice as in:

> *I cannot go to the place ***at*** which I was raped ***at***.

The above sentence is marked by * because it is ungrammatical and can't be used. Whenever you find relative adverbs such as *when*, *where*, *why* and *how*, you don't use a preposition at the end of a sentence.

No. 4 is a construction where the antecedent of *where* ***the place*** is omitted. If you put it back before where, it would be No. 2 sentence.

Note: ***at*** in No. 3 sentence is optional as ***that*** is broadly used as a relative adverb.

***Edit:***

***No. 1 and No. 4 sentences*** have ***to*** after *go* and they are not ***necessary***. You don't need to use ***to*** there.

Comment: Which of them is/are correct?

Comment: @V.V. All the sentences not marked by * are correct.

Comment: I mean those in the question (four).

Comment: I like your answer but l would like to know your opinion about using "to" in the first and the fourth sentences.

Comment: @V.V. If you consider *the place* is omitted, both of them are right, but less popular and idiomatic. You don't need to use *to* in both sentences. I think I had better edit my answer. Thank you for your comment.